# Question on the order of an element in a group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

We know that in a finite group of order say $g$, an element of the group will have order of element $m\leq g$. However, is it necessarily true that at least one element in the group $\textbf{must}$ have order of element $g$?

Comment: In $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ all elements have order two, but the group has order four.

Comment: @ChrisLeary:  except for the element of order one

Comment: @J.W.Tanner - Oops! That was careless of me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If $G$ has order $m$ and $H$ has order $n$, then $G\times H$ has order $mn$. But if $m$ and $n$ are not relatively prime, then no element of $G\times H$ has order $mn$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the complete answer to your question.
A group of order $n$ has an element of order $n$ if and only if the group is cyclic. This statement is an easy exercise.

Comment: (This should go without saying but your answer only works for finite groups. The group $\Bbb Z$ is cyclic; $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$ has the same cardinality as $\Bbb Z$ but is not cyclic.)

Comment: (Oh, and $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ has an element (*e.g.*, $(1,0)$) of order $|\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z|=|\Bbb Z|.$)

Comment: @Shaun, Of course, this does not work for infinite groups. I agree with you. By the way, I note that your example of the Klein group is good because it is minimal.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Consider the Klein four group. It has four elements and yet no element of order four.

Comment: What the . . . Why the vote to delete?